# building computer with fastest clock (overclocking)

Tags: hardware, performance

In my job I prepare loads of data but the program I am using is barely multi-threaded, so - even I am on very fast dual processor machine - I do loads of staring at frozen interface when performing the tasks.

I am thinking about building fast single threaded machine, after some research I found Xeon X5698, but it seems to be not offered by anyone (including eBay), so I am probably destined to buy some 2 or 4 core processor and overclocking it. As I have no experience in that I would like to ask, what is the best processor and motherboard to do it? Are laptop processors good?

Preferably I would like to have something stable running 4-5-6Ghz+ and I do not care if it is dual core - Both AMD and Intel are fine.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites (See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for why -- Basically if we recommend a CPU for you today our advice may very well be obsolete tomorrow. There's very little long-term value for the community at large.)

Answer (score 1):

Overclocking is typically a warranty-voiding act. It is also a terrible idea for system stability.  **Don't** do it.

Instead invest in a machine with the fastest core and bus speeds you can find.  This will probably be the best bang you can get for your buck.

Comment: Will this myth ever die? Overclocking does not void your warranty. You will never find any statement from either AMD or Intel that says that overclocking voids your warranty (especially since such a statement wouldn't be legally valid in the United States anyway). (You may find a statement that your warranty doesn't cover damage caused by overclocking, but that is *not* the same thing?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know of *absolutely no computer manufacturer* that will perform warranty service on a system that has been overclocked, and I have *personally been* ***denied*** *warranty service by Dell* for a workstation I overclocked which subsequently failed. I will however happily retract that portion of my statement if you can provide a credible counterexample. (Now of course if you don't *TELL* them and they don't figure it out that's a different can of worms…)

Comment: Can you link to actual Dell policy on the issue? I'm not convinced by personal anecdotes. It's entirely possible, for example, that you broke the computer by overclocking it. They may have said the warranty doesn't cover damage *caused* by overclocking. We don't know. Dell's official policy statements all say otherwise, that overclocking will not void your warranty, and it would be illegal to void the warranty in the United States (under Magnusson-Moss).

Comment: I really do not care about warranty. My current $1000 processor is slowing me down badly and I desperately need something faster.

Regarding the dell policy, Alienware comes overclocked from the factory. :)